# Group by date range, select max counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble developing a query that achieves the following. I'm trying to determine which user per shift (shifts are 12 hours and run from `7:30AM to 7:30PM`, then again `7:30PM to 7:30AM` period has the most number of records for that shift period.

My Data looks something like this:

```
DateTime            |   UserName
2017-01-01 07:45:00 |   User1
2017-01-01 08:46:00 |   User2
2017-01-01 09:45:00 |   User1
2017-01-01 20:46:00 |   User2
2017-01-01 22:58:00 |   User1
2017-01-01 23:30:00 |   User2
```

Ideally the output I'm looking for would be:

```
DateTime            |   UserName
2017-01-01 07:30:00 |   User1
2017-01-01 19:30:00 |   User2
```

Since User1 had the most records during the shift starting at `2017-01-01 07:30:00 (2017-01-01 07:30:00 - 2017-01-01 19:30:00)`, and User2 had the most records during the shift starting at `2017-01-01 07:30:00 (2017-01-01 19:30:00 - 2017-01-02 7:30:00)`

I hope that made sense, would appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ([DateTime] DATETIME, UserName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('2017-01-01 07:45:00', 'User1'),
('2017-01-01 08:46:00', 'User2'),
('2017-01-01 09:45:00', 'User1'),
('2017-01-01 20:46:00', 'User2'),
('2017-01-01 22:58:00', 'User1'),
('2017-01-01 23:30:00', 'User2')


SELECT UserName, [DateTime] FROM (
    SELECT 
        UserName
        , SHF.SDate [DateTime]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SHF.SDate ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) RN 
    FROM @MyTable T
        CROSS APPLY( VALUES( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.[DateTime], 112) + ' 07:30', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.[DateTime], 112) + ' 19:29' ),
                           ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.[DateTime], 112) + ' 19:30', DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.[DateTime], 112) + ' 07:29'))
        ) SHF ( SDate ,EDate ) 
    WHERE T.[DateTime] BETWEEN SHF.SDate AND SHF.EDate
    GROUP BY 
        UserName
        , SHF.SDate
) AS A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
UserName   DateTime
---------- -----------------------
User1      2017-01-01 07:30
User2      2017-01-01 19:30
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution computes in a CTE a tally of timestamps, for each user, appearing in either the morning or evening shift.  Then, I query the CTE and display either the morning or evening shift depending on which one has the larger tally.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 111) AS DateTime,
        UserName,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN 60*DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime) +
                  DATEPART(MINUTE, DateTime) >= 450 AND
                  60*DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime) +
                  DATEPART(MINUTE, DateTime) < 1170 THEN 1 END) AS m_cnt,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN 60*DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime) +
                  DATEPART(MINUTE, DateTime) < 450 OR
                  60*DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime) +
                  DATEPART(MINUTE, DateTime) >= 1170 THEN 1 END) AS e_cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 111), UserName
)

SELECT
    UserName,
    CASE WHEN m_cnt > e_cnt
         THEN DateTime + ' 07:30:00' ELSE DateTime + ' 19:30:00' END AS DateTime
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    DateTime, UserName;

    UserName    DateTime
1   User1       2017-01-01 07:30:00
2   User2       2017-01-01 19:30:00
```

### Demo